# Trouble toggling a CSS class on dynamically generated elements via event delegation

Tags: javascript, dom, html-lists

So I have `li` elements that my app dynamically generates, and i want to toggle a CSS class when an `li` is clicked. I'm doing this through event delegation, but i don't know how to access the `li` that was clicked in order to make it toggle.

Here is what I have right now:

```
var listElement = document.querySelector("ul");

listElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
        // How would I access the clicked li and apply
        // the .classList.toggle("class")?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) on the [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to find the the clicked list item (`target`). If you've found a list item, remove the `active` class from all the children of the `ul`, and set active on the `target`.

```js
var listElement = document.querySelector("ul");

listElement.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var target = e.target.closest('li');
  
  if(target) {
    e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('li')
      .forEach(li => li.classList.remove('active'));
      
    target.classList.add('active')
  };
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>item 2</span></li>
  <li><span>item 3</span></li>
  <li><span>item 4</span></li>
  <li><span>item 5</span></li>
</ul>
```